# Testing redux middleware with promises

Tags: testing, asynchronous, promise, redux, mocha.js

I want to test this redux middle-ware code for my react app:

```
export const dispatchActionFromPromise = next => (promise, name) => {
      promise.then(data => {
        next({
          type: `${name}_RECEIVED`,
          data
        });
      },
      error => {
        return next({
          type: `${name}_ERROR`,
          error
        });
      });
};

const dataService = store => next => action => {
  next(action);

  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ORGANISATIONS:
      dispatchActionFromPromise(next)(ApiClient.getOrganisations(), GET_ORGANISATIONS);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

};

export default dataService;
```

I want to test `dispatchActionFromPromise()` which takes a promise (`ApiClient.getOrganisations()` returns a promise).

What would be worth testing here, if any, and What would be best approach to test this ?

I am using mocha and chai for testing.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to test getOrganisations() which returns a promise

With unitest, you just test only one function. In your case, the function that you want to test is `getOrganisations()`. So why we care about the context of calling that function?

If you want to write mocha test a function that return promise in reactjs and redux you can write mock funtion to return the fake result. But there is another interesting way which i recomment you use is using redux saga because it make testing is easier. Read office doccument of saga [here](https://redux-saga.js.org/) for more information.